# What is the object in "Anna ate her cold chicken sandwich for lunch"?

Tags: grammar, objects

In this sentence, where is the object?

> Anna ate her cold chicken sandwich for lunch.

Answer (score 10):

> *her cold chicken sandwich*

The question that you can ask to check this is "What did Anna eat?" or "What did Anna eat for lunch?"

Answer (score 6):

Paring it down to the minimum, it's "sandwich", because "her", "cold", and "chicken" are all being used as adjectives. And "for lunch" is a prepositional phrase also being used as an adjective modifying "sandwich". In this phrase, "lunch" is the object of the preposition; it is *not* the object of the sentence.